# "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"?

Tags: arrays, c, warnings

I'm really new to this. I've never done anything like this so I'm having issues with this code. I was given a template to write my code in separate functions like this, although I added the findPos one myself. I'm getting the "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" warning and also my max, min, sum, avg, and position of max and min are obviously not coming out to the right numbers. I was just wondering if anyone can lead me in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int findMin(int arr[], int size);
int findMax(int arr[], int size);
int findSum(int arr[], int size);
int findPos(int arr[], int size);
int size;
int i;
int max;
int min;
int avg;
int sum;
int pos;

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  int arr[size];

  max = findMax;
  min = findMin;
  pos = findPos;
  sum = findSum;
  avg = sum / size;

  printf("max:%7d\tpos:%d\t\n", max, pos);
  printf("min:%7d\tpos:%d\t\n", min, pos);
  printf("avg:%7d\n", avg);
  printf("sum:%7d\n", sum);

  printf("\n");

  printf(" Pos  :   Val\n");
  printf("-------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = (rand() % 1001);
    printf("%4d  :%6d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }
    return 0;
}

int findMin(int arr[], int size)
{
  min = arr[0];
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < min) {
      min = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return min;
}

int findMax(int arr[], int size)
{
  max = arr[0];
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return max;
}

int findSum(int arr[], int size)
{
  sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

int findPos(int arr[], int size)
{
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    pos = i;
  }

  return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
max = findMax;
min = findMin;
pos = findPos;
sum = findSum;
```

You're assigning function pointer, not return value, to integer variable. You have to do something like `max = findMax(arr, size)`. Also in that case, you should assign values to `arr` before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code. Let me iterate through the same

**Populating Data in Created Array**

Since the data has to present the created array before performing any operations,

```
 printf("\n");

  printf(" Pos  :   Val\n");
  printf("-------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = (rand() % 1001);
    printf("%4d  :%6d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }
```

this snippet should be reordered and moved above the function calls and just after the `int arr[size];`

**Function Calls**

All your functions, namely findMax,findMin,findPos,findSum is expecting two parameters

1. arr - array you have created
2. size - the size value read from scanf()

Assuming you want to store the return value from the function in the main int variables max,min,pos,sum,avg

the statements

```
max = findMax;
min = findMin;
pos = findPos;
sum = findSum;
```

should be replaced with function calls like

```
max = findMax(arr, size);
min = findMin(arr, size);
pos = findPos(arr, size);
sum = findSum(arr, size);
```

**The Final Main code will be**

```
int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  int arr[size];

 printf("\n");

  printf(" Pos  :   Val\n");
  printf("-------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = (rand() % 1001);
    printf("%4d  :%6d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }

  max = findMax(arr, size);
  min = findMin(arr, size);
  pos = findPos(arr, size);
  sum = findSum(arr, size);
  avg = sum / size;

  printf("max:%7d\tpos:%d\t\n", max, pos);
  printf("min:%7d\tpos:%d\t\n", min, pos);
  printf("avg:%7d\n", avg);
  printf("sum:%7d\n", sum);
 
    return 0;
}
```